# Qt, аналог fread()

Tags: c++, qt

Мне необходимо считать из файла данные в двоичном виде - сначала несколько `int`, потом `uint8_t`, затем еще кое-что.

Я пытаюсь использовать `QFile::read()` вместо `fread()`, но получается как-то страшно:

```
quint32 newNameLength;
qint64 rCode = file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&newNameLength), 
                         sizeof(quint32));
```

Так вообще можно делать? Если нет, то каков в Qt самый удобный аналог для:

```
uint32_t newNameLength;
size_t rCode = fread(&newNameLength, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать обёртку:

```
size_t qread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, QIODevice &file)
{
    // QIODevice::read не может вернуть число большее, чем мы передали ему в maxSize
    return file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ptr), size * count);
}
```

Но лучше воспользоваться типобезопасностью C++ и поместить всё в шаблоны:

```
// Вариант для массива
template<typename T>
size_t qread(T *out, size_t count, QIODevice &file)
{
    return file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&out), sizeof(T) * count);
}

// Вариант для одиночного элемента
template<typename T>
size_t qread(T &out, QIODevice &file)
{
    return qread(&T, 1, file);
}
```

Comment: Можно-то можно, но эта обертка прячет *маленькую страшность* в *большую*. Особенно будут доставлять инопланетные сообщения об ошибках, если использовать шаблоны. Вообще, мой пример является корректным и адекватным аналогом **fread()**?

Comment: `эта обертка прячет маленькую страшность в большую` — поэтому я и предложил ниже решение через шаблоны на случай, если вам не нужен прямо-таки точный аналог fread. `мой пример является корректным и адекватным аналогом fread()`— да, является.

Comment: единственное надо помнить. что при переносе файла между BE и LE это всё сломается... если не добавить преобразование после чтения конечно...

Answer (score 1):

Конечно так, можно, или ещё проще:

```
quint32 newNameLength;
qint64 rCode = file.read((char*)&newNameLength, sizeof(quint32));
```

так как понятно, что нужен просто адрес, разработчикам надо было бы сразу сделать первый аргумент, как **void ***. Qt вообще частенько адреса, как **char *** передаёт, что плохо в отличии от **memcpy**.